# How do I change the back button on a UINavigationControler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

In the view I want to change it for I have the following code but it fails.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //Logout button
    UIBarButtonItem * logout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
    logout.title = @"Logout";
    nav_delegate.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logout;
    [logout release];
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer. In the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"X";
    //Logout button
    UIBarButtonItem * logout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logout;
    [logout release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementing backBarButtonItem is for the super view controller which uses pushViewController:subViewController.

For example, if you've pushed a view controller for its super view controller Logout:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:subViewController animated:YES];
```

Then, you should've implemented backBarButtonItem in the super view, which is Logout view, **NOT in the pushed subViewController**.

So, to implement backBarButtonItem, you do it in super view Logout, like:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:logoutViewTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

You can do this in -(void)viewDidLoad for static use, or in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated for dynamic use, for setting the title without allocating and initializing.

One more tip: In interface builder, there is input field for backBarButtonItem title. But if you didn't enter, you must allocate and initialize the backBarButton with title in .m files, like the code above. If you've entered the title for static use, I believe you can change it simply by using:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:logoutViewTitle];
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I got what you meant but changing the property in the UINavigationController never worked. It works perfectly when modifying it on the UIView I push.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `backBarButtonItem` on the previous view controller (the one that you will return to when you press the back button).

Comment: I added the code on the previous view controller's viewDidLoad method and it still failed. I made sure I replaced nav_delegate.navigationController with self. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're coding, but maybe a modal view controller would suit it better. When I think of "Cancel", I think of modal view controllers instead of navigation controllers.

Comment: I don;t mind using the stack style navigation. In this particular case the program should go to the root view and the back button should have the title "Logout."

Comment: Ah, OK. You know the root view controller has no back button? In that case you should use the `leftBarButtonItem` of the visible view controller. Check "Updating the Navigation Bar" in the help docs for `UINavigationController`, it gives the list of rules for what gets shown in each position of a bar.

Comment: I'm having another look. The button is supposed to take the user back to the root view... I almost have it working now.