# self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"back" does not work for the next view controller?

Tags: ios

I know  `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` is set for the next view controller;

In view Controller A:
when I use

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"back";
```

it does not work.
However when

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

it works successfully!
Why…..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the back button on a UINavigationControler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092298/how-do-i-change-the-back-button-on-a-uinavigationcontroler)

Comment: it is different.. i push another view controller, but the backItem's title of the pushed view does not changed when i use method one but changed by method 2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the back button is either:

1. The title of the previous view controller The name of the previous
2. view controller's navigation item back button

If you are setting the back button for the current view controller's navigation item you are not setting the button that get's displayed in the current view. You are in fact setting the back button that will be used if you push another view controller from it.

Comment: yes i push another view controller, but the backItem's title of the pushed view does not changed when i use method one but changed by method 2...